# Как делать редирект при клике по adsense?

Tags: php, javascript, java, html, google-adsense

На сайте кто-то делает большое кол-во кликов по `adsense` специально, из-за этого уже получил бан на 30 дней.

Но вот бан прошел решил сделать так. Если кто-то кликнул по рекламе открывается сайт рекламодателя, а так же еще одна вкладка с указанной мной ссылкой там идет запись в куки и в течении дня больше реклама не показывается.

Но вот проблема. Раньше я делал так - к тегу `div` приписывал атрибут `onclick="ссылка указанная мною"`, но сейчас не получается. При клике по adsense сайт рекламодателя открывается в новой вкладке, а указанная мной ссылка не открывается. Как реализовать такое средствами javascript?

Просто его я не знаю и только собираюсь изучать. Основной проблемой является то, что в сам `iframe` от google я не могу ничего писать, он подгружается сам при вставке из рекламного кода. Как реализовать открытие новой вкладки с указанной мной ссылкой при клике по рекламе adsense?

Answer (score 1):

Вы правильно заметили, что не имеете доступ к iframe; соответственно событие на div вы повесить не можете, т..к все события будет принимать уже iframe.
Возможно вы можете с помощью js ловить событие потери фокуса окна

```
$(window).focus(function() {
    //ajax
});

$(window).blur(function() {
    //ajax
});
```

Также проделать тоже самое через координаты, но в любом случае вы будете лишь "гадать"

Comment: Извините , я не особо знаком с JS . Так что не особо понял вас . Видимо придется оставить все так . Надеюсь этот анонимный кликер больше не объявится и я не получу еще один бан в adsense . Спасибо за помощь